# How to setup Jetty development environment?

Tags: java, jetty, war

I have Jetty 6.1.24 in my production environment installed on Debian in the following way:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk, jetty, libjetty-extra-java
```

And for my development environment I've downloaded Jetty 6.1.24 from here:
http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6.1.24/jetty-6.1.24.zip

But often my war-files that work perfectly on development Jetty fail with errors on production.

How can I make my development environment (on Windows without deb packages) behave exactly as a debian-installed Jetty?

Comment: What errors do you get ?

Comment: For example, with wro4j: ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Cannot create model using any of provided factories, and also some problems were with javamail and also mybatis and so on, although there were no exceptions in dev.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's posible that your prod and dev environment don't have the same libraries installed. Look at $JETTY_HOME/libs. dev may refer to libraries on your dev machine that are not installed on prod.

Maybe apt-get installs a completely diferent Jetty version. Try to download the same ZIP version to your prod, unpack and run from $JETTY_HOME/bin/jetty.sh.

Comment: Yes, I also think that it is because of some libraries missed or having incompatible versions. But I don't want to modify my production, instead I want to make my dev environment be equivalent to production. But if I simply replace my development Jetty libraries with those from /usr/share/jetty/lib - then Jetty even fails to start.

Comment: the debian guys build those deb's themselves so they are going to be different from the distributions we build ourselves